# Is "proof by counterexample" a legitimate proof?

Tags: proof-writing, notation, soft-question, philosophy, publishing

Suppose that I am proving the following proposition:

> **Proposition 1.** For some $a$, $f(x)=ax^2$ is not an increasing function.

I "proved" the proposition by providing a numerical counterexample.

My question is:

1. Can "proposition 1" be called as a proposition?
2. If I write a formal proof, starting with *proof* and end with *Q.E.D.*, but everything in the proof is a counterexample, **shall I call this "proof by counterexample" or "proof by contradiction"?**

I am asking because I don't know if I should start the proof by saying "by contradiction" or "by counterexample".

---

**Motivation:** From what I learnt we can prove things via counterexamples. But [this wiki link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematical_Proof/Methods_of_Proof/Counterexamples#:%7E:text=A%20proof%20by%20counterexample%20is,that%20contradicts%20a%20universal%20statement.) says that proof by counterexample is not technically a proof. I think "proof by counterexample" is not a proof technique but counterexample is one thing we could use in a "proof by contradiction".

---

Updated. I am mostly interested in the formal language and format of writing the proof, rather than the actual proof of the proposition 1.

Comment: The "counterexample" you provide is just an example. Since the proposition asserts that some example exists, what you prove is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample is (just as its name states) a particular case that shows that the theorem is invalid.

A contradiction shows that there is a logical inconsistency inherent in the proposed theorem.  It need not include an example whatsoever.

Very different things.

Answer (score 4):

Wikibooks are not necessarily up to the standard that, say, a Wikipedia article would be, and whatever this book is trying to say doesn't really make sense.

A counterexample to a statement is a complete and valid proof that the statement is false.

If I were to write up a proof of this statement, I would probably write something like the following:

> **Proposition.**  $f(x) = ax^2$ is not an increasing function for any value of $a$.  (By "increasing" we mean *strictly* increasing, i.e.
> that $f(x) < f(y)$ for any $x < y$.)
>
> **Proof.**  Notice that, for instance, $f(-1) = a = f(1)$ for all $a$.

Comment: The statement I am proving is something like "for some $a$, $ax^2$ is not an increasing function". Also the actual proof is one page long so I think I'd be better to start with a phrase like "proof by contradiction" or "proof by counterexample" so that people can have a better idea of what I am doing. Sorry for being unclear at the first place and truly appreciate your answer!

Comment: In that case, I would say "Take a = 1.  f(-1) = 1 and f(0) = 0, so f is not increasing."  The proof shouldn't be anywhere near a page long.

Comment: If you do have a much longer proof, you could say something like "Assume for the sake of argument that $f$ is increasing" at the beginning, and then at the end "... which is a contradiction, so the assumption that $f$ is increasing must be wrong."

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I am proving a statement with the logic structure like the one written in the question. I am more interested in learning the proper proof languages and formats.